# An extension of the mean-value theorem for integrals?

Tags: integration, surreal-analysis

The mean value theorem for integrals states that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a, b]$ and $g$ never changes sign on $[a, b]$, then there exists some $c\in [a, b]$ such that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx = f(c)\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx.$$

Is it also true that, for any $C\in[a, b]$, there exists some $D \in [a, b]$ (dependant on $C$) such that

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x) dx = f(C)\int_{a}^{D} g(x) dx $$?

Answer (score 1):

No, a counterexample would be a function that is negative at and around $a$, but starts becoming positive as it approaches b, such that

$$\int_{a}^b f(x)g(x) dx > 0$$

Let $f(x)$ be negative around $a$. Now, for *any* value you pick, $f(x)$ could be negative. If we let $g(x)$ be strictly positive this will mean that

$$f(C)\int_{a}^D g(x) dx < 0$$
for some $C$.

Edit: On a side note, am I correct that this question is a better fit for Math StackExchange?